# Not able to invoke web services using web app which was deployed in Azure

Tags: web-services, azure, intellij-14, corda

I have a deployed html file by creating web app in Azure and hosted using FTP tool. when I hit the run in intellij, able to submit the values using html file and able to hit the web services. but am not able to hit the web services when i trying to deploy and run the nodes in command prompt.

Comment: And where is the connection to the added tags?

Comment: It's in relation to a CorDapp.

Comment: can't get you. added tags?

Comment: is there any solution @joel

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand the question.

Comment: am deployed and run the cordapp using command prompt. after that i can able to hit the web services using postman. but not able to hit the web services using web page(html file) which was created under resources folder.

Comment: when i  run the project using intellij, i can able to hit web services using postman as well as web page.

Comment: I'm guessing there are some hard-coded paths in your web content. Could you host the file someone and link to it?

Comment: yeah.. I have hosted the file and linked too using http post. hard coded in the sense?i have hard coded the url path in web content file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web app does not have the proper url of your web server.

Feel free to see an example of how we had build a front end web app at: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/client/src/main/resources

The front-end is simple angular web app.